# Solve this integral of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be invertible and define $e^A = \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$. Suppose $\lim \limits_{t\to\infty} e^{-A^T A t} = 0$.

Show $$A^{\dagger} = \int \limits_{0}^\infty e^{-A^T A t} A dt$$
where $A^\dagger$ is pseudo-inverse of $A$.

Comment: Pseudo-inverse of an invertible matrix ?

Comment: @NoMan the claim is not true in general! It holds $A^{-1}= \int_0^\infty e^{-A^TA}dt A^T$. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A^TA$ is symmetric, it has real eigenvalues and is diagonalizable. Moreover, all eigenvalues are non-zero thus positive. 
Now let me prove $\lambda^{-1} = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} dt$ for
all possible eigenvalues $\lambda> 0$. This is a standard integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} dt = -\frac1\lambda\lim_{t\to\infty} ( e^{-\lambda t}-1) = \frac1\lambda.
$$
This shows
$$
(A^TA)^{-1} = \int_0^\infty e^{-A^TAt}\ dt.
$$
Multiplying from the right with $A^T$ yields
$$
A^{-1} = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T= \int_0^\infty e^{-A^TAt}A^T\ dt.
$$

---

Note that the originally claimed equality
$$
A^{-1} =  \int_0^\infty e^{-A^TAt}A\ dt
$$
is not true in general. It is only true if and only if 
$$
A^{-1}A^{-T}A=A^{-1},
$$
which is equivalent to $A=A^T$.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that $A$ is diagonalisable (or even symmetric, because eigen-values of $A^TA$ are quite different from eigen-values of $A$ otherwise)? Since $(A^T.A)$ is diagonalizable with positive eigen-values, you proved that $\int_0^\infty \exp(-A^T.A.t) dt = (A^T.A)^{-1}$. Hence $\int_0^\infty \exp(-A^T.A.t) A.dt = A^{-1}.(A^T)^{-1}.A$. So the OP's claim is false if $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the note! you are right. Will repair the answer tonight.